# Is there a way to convert/export a Google Sheets Chart into Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-macros

Simply, I have created a chart by inserting a chart and adding range/settings etc.

But I have realised that when resizing the chart (by recording a macro) all the settings are lost.

Is there a way to convert the Google Sheets Chart into Google Apps Script, otherwise I think I will have to re-create the graph in Google Apps Script. Just hoping to save some time with this query.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Incorrect tags will hide your question. See tags section of [ask].

Comment: Hi there @JMusy! I don't understand what is "*Google Scripts Chart*". Could you please clarify me what is that language?

Comment: Google Apps Script (GAS) is based on javascript and used to add extra features to Google Sheets files. (Similar to VBA in Exel).
Within Google Sheets a graph is called a 'Chart'.

Comment: @JMusy, thank you for your clarification. I understand that there exists [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), and there are also charts on Sheets. Could you please explain to me what you mean to export a *Scripts Chart* to Apps Script?

Comment: My apologies @Jacques-GuzelHeron. I have edited the question. 'Google Sheets Chart' to 'Google Apps Script' is the query. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to create a graph in Apps Script in a similar way that you did in a Sheet. If I understood it right, then you can complete your aim by using [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts). You can see a full example in the linked documentation.

Just to clarify it, first you would need to create a table using [`DataTableBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table-builder). This table should be equal to the one in your Sheet. After that you can [create a graph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts#methods_4) based on that table. Please, ask me any question if you still have doubts.